# How to copy an entire content database to another server

Tags: backup

I just installed a new farm, we want to copy from another server (prod), all content from a web application, fortunately its only one content db,

I already have the dba doing the backup, and the restore, but what should I do in the new server?

shouuld I create a new web application with the same content db name?
should I created mount-spcontent database after the restore?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a SQL backup (content database), you can create a `new web app -> site coll` and then attach the database.

Refer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582(v=office.14).aspx